# ggplot2 confusion matrix geom_text labeling

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've plotted a confusion matrix (predicting 5 outcomes) in R using ggplot and scales for geom_text labeling.

The way `geom_text(aes(label = percent(Freq/sum(Freq)))` is written in code, it's showing Frequency of each box divided by sum of all observations, but what I want to do is get Frequency of each box divided by sum Frequency for each Reference.

In other words, instead of A,A = 15.8%,
it should be A,A = 15.8%/(0.0%+0.0%+0.0%+0.0%+15.8%%) = 100.0%

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

valid_actual <- as.factor(c("A","B","B","C","C","C","E","E","D","D","A","A","A","E","E","D","D","C","B"))
valid_pred   <- as.factor(c("A","B","C","C","E","C","E","E","D","B","A","B","A","E","D","E","D","C","B"))

cfm <- confusionMatrix(valid_actual, valid_pred)


ggplotConfusionMatrix <- function(m){
  mytitle <- paste("Accuracy", percent_format()(m$overall[1]),
                   "Kappa", percent_format()(m$overall[2]))
  p <-
    ggplot(data = as.data.frame(m$table) ,
           aes(x = Reference, y = Prediction)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = log(Freq)), colour = "white") +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "green") +
    geom_text(aes(x = Reference, y = Prediction, label = percent(Freq/sum(Freq)))) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    ggtitle(mytitle)
  return(p)
}

ggplotConfusionMatrix(cfm)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that, as far as I know, ggplot is not able to do group calculation. See [this recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412522/r-ggplot-on-the-fly-calculation-by-grouping-variable) for similar question.

To solve your problem you should take advantage of the `dplyr`package.

This should work

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(caret)

library(dplyr)

valid_actual <- as.factor(c("A","B","B","C","C","C","E","E","D","D","A","A","A","E","E","D","D","C","B"))

valid_pred   <- as.factor(c("A","B","C","C","E","C","E","E","D","B","A","B","A","E","D","E","D","C","B"))

cfm <- confusionMatrix(valid_actual, valid_pred)

ggplotConfusionMatrix <- function(m){
  mytitle <- paste("Accuracy", percent_format()(m$overall[1]),
                   "Kappa", percent_format()(m$overall[2]))
  data_c <-  mutate(group_by(as.data.frame(m$table), Reference ), percentage = 
percent(Freq/sum(Freq)))
  p <-
    ggplot(data = data_c,
           aes(x = Reference, y = Prediction)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = log(Freq)), colour = "white") +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "green") +
    geom_text(aes(x = Reference, y = Prediction, label = percentage)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    ggtitle(mytitle)
  return(p)
}

ggplotConfusionMatrix(cfm)
```

And the result:

[image: Confusion matrix]